# DatGridView Displayes data when initialised but then has no data programatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView being populated from an excel data source.  It loads fine and displays the data when the form is initialised. However once loaded it has no data.

I have a binding source in my form class:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
```

And this is my code to get the data from excel and populate the data grid view:

```
public void GetList(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        try
        {
            SystemData.DataTable excelDataTable = new SystemData.DataTable();

            if (fileExt == "*.xlsx")
            {
                OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO';"); // > 2007
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oleConn); // select columns
                oleAdpt.Fill(excelDataTable); // fill table
            }
            else
            {
                OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"); // < 2007
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oleConn); // select columns
                oleAdpt.Fill(excelDataTable); // fill table
            }

            bindingSource.DataSource = excelDataTable;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
            dataGridView1.Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image: Image - graphical data grid view]

Once its loaded and displays the data graphically it instantly returns no rows, columns, cells, data.  Its empty.

If i try get some data like how many rows i get nothing:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());
    }
```

[image: Image - return the number of rows]

Any help correcting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were it my code I think I might have done something like `var oleConn = new OleDbConnection($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={fileName};Extended Properties='Excel {(fileExt==".xlsx"?12:8)}.0;HDR=NO';");` rather than the if/else

Comment: There must be something else going on. The posted code appears to work as expected. The `MessageBox` in the grids `CellContentClick` event displays the proper number of rows. In addition, I never experienced what you described… _”Once its loaded and displays the data graphically it instantly returns no rows, columns, cells, data. Its empty.”_ … ? Is there something else going on after the grids data source is set and before the user clicks the contents of a cell?

Comment: no that's as far as Ive gone with it just trying to get past this block.  Only code ive got in this form is to populate the datagrid and the button click

Comment: I suggest you trace your code. I copy/paste the posted code and it works as expected. I am sure what you say is true, however, the problem does not appear to be coming from the posted code. In addition, the message box picture could NOT possibly be correct given we can “see” there are rows in the grid. Put a break-point on the message box code and check what the values are.

Comment: will look into the file extension option in the oleDBConnection line to simplify.  Cheers

Comment: Will do, the form is being launched from command line inside a 3rd part app so tracing is not so simple for me being a novice.  Will spend some time and report back.

Comment: Got the debugger working in outside application.  Finally found the tick box at the bottom of debug options for enabling debugger in native code.  Your right the code works as expected in a new sln without any references to autodesk products.  For some reason in the one i was working in when i posted this question the data gridview has no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a datagridview bound (ultimately) to a data table, if you want to know something about the data or do something to it, do it to the data table directly, not via the datagridview. After the fill method finishes, only thing you have got a reference to, that can give you this directly, is the binding source

```
MessageBox.Show((bindingSource.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Count);
```

Rather than casting the BS’s datasource to datatable all the time it might just be easier to have the datatable be a class level variable too

If you want to know something about the current row in the DGV, ask the BindingSource. Current means the row that data would go into if the user started typing.

```
bindingSource.Current
```

Current is typed to return object, but for you is a DataRowView which is what a bindingSource uses to represent the row when it is bound to a datatable. If you want the underlying row in the data table itself, use DataRowView’s Row property, otherwise you can mostly treat a datarowview like a datarow in terms of reading and writing data

```
(bindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row //a datarow

(bindingSource.Current as DataRowView)["name"]
```

= "John";
(bindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row ["name"]
= "John";

I’d recommend the only time you ask the DGV for anything is when you’ve select highlighted multiple rows in it and are using eg it’s SelectedRows collection. In those cases, strive to then access the underlying row via the DataBoundItem property which returns the bindingsource’s DataRowView, which can then be used to get the data table’s row via its Row property

```
(DGV.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row
```

Plenty of layers to this onion eh?